Router configuration. Unable to Connect to Hostapd WiFi Network
I have set up a wireless network using hostapd on my Banana Pi R3 router running Ubuntu 22.04.
hostapd configuration
$ sudo cat /etc/hostapd/hostapd_wlan0_gemma.conf 
# hostapd configuration file
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ssid=GemmaNode
country_code=EU
channel=7
hw_mode=g
ht_capab=[LDPC][HT20][HT40-][HT40+][GF][SHORT-GI-20][SHORT-GI-40][TX-STBC][RX-STBC1]
#ht_capab=[HT40-][SHORT-GI-20][SHORT-GI-40]  # Try this
ieee80211n=1
auth_algs=1
wmm_enabled=1
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=mypassword
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK 
wpa_pairwise=CCMP
nas_identifier=glutamate-vlan500

Problem
When I try to connect to the WiFi network from another computer, the connection fails.
Questions

Why is the client not acknowledging the authentication response?
How can I resolve the connection issue to ensure successful
authentication and connection?

hostapd Logs
When I start hostapd, I get the following log messages indicating an issue with authentication:
wlan0: Event RX_MGMT (18) received
mgmt::auth
authentication: STA=00:e1:b0:10:2c:df auth_alg=0 auth_transaction=1 status_code=0 wep=0 seq_ctrl=0x5f90
wlan0: STA 00:e1:b0:10:2c:df IEEE 802.11: authentication OK (open system)
wlan0: STA 00:e1:b0:10:2c:df MLME: MLME-AUTHENTICATE.indication(00:e1:b0:10:2c:df, OPEN_SYSTEM)
wlan0: STA 00:e1:b0:10:2c:df MLME: MLME-DELETEKEYS.request(00:e1:b0:10:2c:df)
authentication reply: STA=00:e1:b0:10:2c:df auth_alg=0 auth_transaction=2 resp=0 (IE len=0) (dbg=handle-auth)
nl80211: send_mlme - da=00:e1:b0:10:2c:df noack=0 freq=0 no_cck=0 offchanok=0 wait_time=0 no_encrypt=0 fc=0xb0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_AUTH) nlmode=3
nl80211: send_mlme - Use bss->freq=2442
nl80211: send_mlme -> send_frame_cmd
nl80211: CMD_FRAME freq=2442 wait=0 no_cck=0 no_ack=0 offchanok=0
CMD_FRAME - hexdump(len=30): b0 00 00 00 00 e1 b0 10 2c df 00 0c 43 26 60 00 00 0c 43 26 60 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00
nl80211: Frame TX command accepted; cookie 0x91
nl80211: Drop oldest pending send frame cookie 0x0
nl80211: Event message available
nl80211: Drv Event 60 (NL80211_CMD_FRAME_TX_STATUS) received for wlan0
nl80211: MLME event 60 (NL80211_CMD_FRAME_TX_STATUS) on wlan0(00:0c:43:26:60:00) A1=00:e1:b0:10:2c:df A2=00:0c:43:26:60:00
nl80211: MLME event frame - hexdump(len=30): b0 00 00 00 00 e1 b0 10 2c df 00 0c 43 26 60 00 00 0c 43 26 60 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00
nl80211: Frame TX status event A1=00:e1:b0:10:2c:df stype=11 cookie=0x91 ack=0
wlan0: Event TX_STATUS (16) received
mgmt::auth cb
wlan0: STA 00:e1:b0:10:2c:df IEEE 802.11: did not acknowledge authentication response

wlan0 configuration
$ sudo cat /etc/systemd/network/30-wlan0.network 
[Match]
Name=wlan0

[Network]
#ConfigureWithoutCarrier=true
BindCarrier=eth0
#static setup
Address=192.168.0.1/24
Gateway=192.168.0.1
DNS=192.168.0.1
IPForward=yes
#DHCPServer=yes
DHCPServer=no


Change the address & gateway to the IP assigned to the interface. 192.168.0.xxx. Only use .1 for DNS.

Hi Jay! I changed the address to 192.168.0.10/24 in the wlan0 configuration file with no luck. The computer I am running hostapd if a router not connected to the internet, it just provides a wired and wireless networks bridged together
